# Addthis, add the appropiate html attributes to the tags after the DOM in order to make it validate

Tags: jquery, addthis

I am trying to validate my page and I use addthis.

I load the code async and I initialize it with jQuery after the dom is ready.

```
function initAddThis(){
    var addthis_config = {ui_use_css : false}   
    addthis.init();
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($){      
    initAddThis();
});
```

Now the validator says:

> Attribute g:plusone:size not allowed on element a at this point

Here is the html part with problems:

```
<a class="addthis_button_google_plusone google_plusone" g:plusone:size="medium"></a>
```

Now, is there a way to add the appropriate attributes (g:plusone:size="medium") to the tag after the HTML is downloaded? How can I do this?

Ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The first thing you need to do when working with namespaces is to set
>   the default namespace. You do this by using the xmlns attribute on the
>   root element of your document. In XHTML that would be the  tag:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
```

http://webdesign.about.com/od/xmlnamespaces/a/xml_namespaces.htm

> The root element of the document must contain an xmlns declaration for
>   the XHTML namespace [XMLNS]. The namespace for XHTML is defined to be
>   http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml. An example root element might look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html 
     PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Virtual Library</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a class="addthis_button_google_plusone google_plusone" g:plusone:size="medium"></a>
  </body>
</html>
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#normative